# Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object in redis

Tags: c#, redis, bloomberg

after using wrapper, large volume from queue, got this error:

**initially there is no error when it save, after several minutes, it got this error
and i discover dump.rdb maintain at 1 KB size. it seems do not change after large volume save message**

> Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object

at `RedisClass.GetInstnace().Store(Msg)`

```
if (SQLQueue == null)
  SQLQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<BMsg>();
SQLQueue.TryDequeue(out BloomberMsg);
if (BloomberMsg != null)
{
  RedisClass.GetInstnace().Store(BloomberMsg);
  RedisClass.GetInstnace().Save();
}

public class BloomMsg
        {
            public Message msg  {get; set;}
            public String TypeOfMsg { get; set; }

        }

foreach (Message msg in eventObj)
                {
                    logger.Debug(msg.ToString());
                    if (SQLQueue == null)
                        SQLQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<BloomMsg>();

                    BloomMsg b = new BloomMsg();
                    b.msg = msg;
                    b.TypeOfMsg = TypeOfMsg;
                    SQLQueue.Enqueue(b);

                }
```

Comment: you should debug the content of `Msg`

Comment: it is just a simple message, initially there is no error when it save, after several minutes, it got this error